# Can I pre-populate a search in iOS PHPicker?

Tags: ios, photokit, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

Let's say I have an iOS "Cats" app that I want my users to select photos. Is there a way to open PHPicker with a search term pre-populated with "cats"?

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd need to build your own picker.